# Checking for unique item in a list mathematically

Tags: python, algorithm, math, set

I've been solving some LeetCode problems and came across an interesting problem. I'll paste it below for your reference:

> Given an array where every element occurs three times, except one element which occurs only once. Find the element that occurs once. The expected time complexity is O(n) and O(1) extra space.

> Input: arr[] = {12, 1, 12, 3, 12, 1, 1, 2, 3, 3}
>
> Output: 2
>
> In the given array all element appear three times except 2 which appears once.

My solution was to use a hashmap to try and solve this. I came across a mathematical solution for this though, and was wondering why this works:

```
def singleNumber(nums):

    # applying the formula.
    return (3 * sum(set(nums)) - sum(nums)) / 2
```

If any one can help me understand why this works, it would be great :)

Comment: But why did you use a `hashmap`?

Comment: I'm not very clear on time-complexity, I'm guessing it doesn't fit the criteria for the answer but it makes things simpler for me at least.

Comment: Surely "the formula" refers to an explanation right above/below the code? Where did you find it?

Comment: Not sure what part of the solution you don't understand. You can `print set(nums)` and `print sum(set(nums))` and `print(sum(nums))`. The rest is pretty straightforward.

Comment: Its not fully related to the function, but does what OP requires in O(n) time complexity: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-element-that-appears-once/

Comment: @user3386109 pretty much why this works mathematically. Why does this calculation give us the answer we're looking for here? Unfortunately the explanation where I found this wasn't very clear on that part.

Comment: I thought you said this was *your* solution. Where did you find this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is actually pretty straightforward. Consider the following example:

```
a = [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3]
```

For the first part of the formula, `3 * sum(set(nums))`, it will sum the vector as if it had 3 elements of each, i.e. `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`, which would result in `18`. It then subtracts `sum(nums)`, which is equal to `12`. So the difference between `18` and `12` is exactly the 2 additional instances of the number 3, the number that appears only once in the original vector. Then divide by 2 to find its value, which is 3.

Comment: The way you explained that resonated with me 'it will sum the vector as if it had 3 elements of each'

Comment: But does this note violate the requirement of `O(1)` space? as creating a set of the numbers make this `O(n)` space.

Comment: I agree w/ CryptoNoob, does not seem like O(1) space.  That part has something to do with the "3" since it is given (I'm presuming you do not know the size of the array a priori).  Also, does doing O() stuff with python make sense (specifically, set is not O(1); its O() will depend on how it is done in the background, right?  I'd use C.

Answer (score 5):

The solution you found isn't really a "mathematical" solution of the sort you sometimes see for these problems.  `set(nums)` creates a collection of these numbers in which each distinct one occurs only once -- similar to what you would do with your hashmap.

You know that sum(nums) = 3*(sum of all numbers) - 2*(unique number).  So if you calculate 3*(sum of all numbers) from the `set`, then you can just subtract `sum(nums)` and divide by 2 to find the unique one one.

There *is* a mathematical solution that doesn't require you to build a collection, though:

```
def findUnique(arr):
    c1=0
    c2=0
    for v in arr:
        carry = c1&v
        c1 ^= v
        c2 ^= carry
        threes = c1&c2
        c1 &= ~threes
        c2 &= ~threes
    return c1
```

You can try it here:
https://ideone.com/BPoJY5

In this solution the bits of `c1` and `c2` are used as parallel counters to count the occurrences of each bit in the values.  The calculation is done mod 3, so at the end only the bits with a number of occurrences that aren't divisible by 3 remain.